# Create element after click on doesn't append

Tags: jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#playerForm .add-box').click(function(){
        addplayerList();
    });
});

function addplayerList(){
    $('.list-box').append('<p>second</p>');
}
```

I am trying to make a function which will create a new line of HTML after I press the `add` button. I have no idea what I did wrong. I checked the code and I believe it should work but some how after I click on `add` the content `<p>second</p>` shows and disappears right away.

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Tedeee/wmzoroag/2/) - it has an error after I click `add`

Comment: Any specific reason for using `post` method? If none, then you can change `method="post"` to `method="get"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because the `button` click is submitting the form. You need to call `preventDefault()` in the `click()` handler to stop this.

```
$('#playerForm .add-box').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    addplayerList();
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/wmzoroag/3/)

Alternatively you can just amend your HTML to change the `type` of the button from a `submit` (which is the default) just to a plain button:

```
<button class="add-box" type="button">add</button>
```

Comment: thank i didt know it somehow make the button to submit that form , thank friend.

Answer (score 1):

The fiddle seems to work fine for me apart from the default behaviour of clicking the link causing the error you describe to show.

To avoid the error after click, you can do this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#playerForm .add-box').click(function(){
        addplayerList();
        return false;
    });
});
```

The `return false;` prevents the default behaviour of the click, which is to redirect to the `href` attribute.

https://jsfiddle.net/wmzoroag/4/